# Mandatory field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make sure that field is mandatory ? Here is what I mean

I have the following mysql table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `new` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is query with no data for phone

```
insert into new values(1, 'm', '');
```

But the query runs fine. What should be done so that mysql returns an error if there is no data for phone field? I can do that validation by php, but I'm curious how to do that in mysql.

Comment: An empty string is different to NULL. If you want it to fail you should pass Null to your query not an empty string.

Comment: In SQL you would add constraint (e.g. `CHECK(DATALENGTH(phone) > 0)` ) but mySQL doesn't implement this feature :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new VALUES(1,'m',NULL)
```

will cause error.
If you want to check whether is the phone number field is a blank string,
you can use a trigger in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly setting the default value of the 'phone' column to NULL would make it fail insertion because it would end up null if you did not specify it.

Otherwise you're going to need to omit the phone column for the default to kick in, say in php you'd use empty($phone) ? null : $phone; or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I have a feeling the `'' != null`. What happens if you run

```
insert into new(id, name) values (1, 'test');
```

I bet you get an insert error...

Anyway, I think its probably better to be validating in PHP than waiting till you get to the database... inserts are expensive...

Comment: You should do both. Use PHP (or whatever language your app is written in) and validate data upfront to help the user with useful messages. But always keep the database constraints up, because that is the last line of defense against bad data, which might come from anywhere in the code, not just the UI.

Comment: oh definitely! Don't be lazy and leave out db constraints, they are absolutely required - like Daniel says, they ensure your stored data is good (well, as good as your design allows). Sorry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

'' as the 3rd option doesnt make the value of phone null.. It is just equal to a blank string thats all.
if you want to see an error, replace '' with NULL.