# Trigger to fail query

Tags: mysql

How to create trigger (mysql) which to fail sql query if some of fields have no data ?

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `new` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Let`s say I have this query

```
INSERT INTO new values(1, 'Bu', '');
```

I want that query to fail if there is no data for phone field.

Comment: Why don't you just `INSERT` NULL instead of the empty string, like recommended here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422381/mandatory-field-mysql

Answer (score 0):

phone field is declared as int so you are sending and empty char use this

```
INSERT INTO new values(1, 'Bu', o);
```

You may change the property of phone to varchar() or at least remove the NOT NULL property so you can insert null values.

Comment: @georgevich I misunderstood your question.                          Your Insert statement will fail because it looking for an int value. So ignore my post

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new values(1, 'Bu', NULL);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO new (`id`, `name`) values(1, 'Bu');
```

Comment: It wont work because the phone field is decleared as            `phone` int(11) NOT NULL so it may never be null

Comment: Exactly! You previously stated "I want that query to fail if there is no data for phone field." and yes, it would not work, because it would fail.

Comment: Hmmm, there is an misunderstanding :(